# Change color of horizontal progress bar programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-progressbar

How can I change the color of a horizontal progress bar programmatically without creating a custom drawable?

I tried using this code from another question

```
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

but that does not fix it, as the entire progress bar goes red. In the comments there was one user saying to use `Mode.MULTIPLY` but the entire progress bar just goes black. I also tried using `SRC_ATOP`without success.

My ProgressBar is defined as follows:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
```

Is there any other way to solve this without using custom drawables?

Comment: of course,  use a <layer-list> tag in your xml, and change only one layer

Answer (score -1):

`android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal` contains a `drawable` ; create a `drawable` it described;